# How can I use newly-added constructor arguments of a class in an overridden method called during the superclass's constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

If I have a class `Foo` which calls a method like `someMethod` in its constructor, and I want to override `someMethod` to make use of constructor arguments which I have newly-added in this subclass, how can I do this?

Let's suppose that `Foo` has a noargs constructor which calls `someMethod`. What I **wish I could do** is something like:

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    private String x;
    private String y;
    public Bar(String x, String y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        // do stuff with x and y
    }
}
```

Of course, I can't do that because Java insists that the call to the superclass constructor is on the first line of the subclass constructor. If I moved it to the first line then it would be called before x and y were initialised and therefore `someMethod` would not use their values as passed into my constructor.

It seems I can get around this using inner classes, but it's pretty horrible.

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    private String x;
    private String y;
    private Foo baz;
    public class Foobar extends Foo {
        @Override
        public void someMethod {
            // do stuff with Foo.this.x and Foo.this.y
        }
    }
    public Bar(String x, String y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        baz = new Foobar();
    }
    // override ALL of the remaining methods, including someMethod, delegating them to baz
}
```

This is a horrible solution, is this an accepted pattern and is there any better way?

NOTE: To clarify in case it's not obvious, the class `Foo` is not under the developer's control (e.g. it's part of a third-party library). The developer is trying to extend `Foo` and so any design decisions made by `Foo` (e.g. non-final method called from constructor) are not things the developer can influence.

EDIT: People are asking in the comments if `someMethod` is private. It is not private, if it was then I wouldn't be able to override it. Here is an example of said class `Foo` to illustrate:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        // some other stuff...
        someMethod();
    }
    public void someMethod() {
        // nothing of consequence
    }
    // some other methods, which aren't relevant to the question
}
```

Comment: What problem do you actually want to solve? This looks like a workaround for something that could be achieved easier. A special note: be cateful when calling non-final methods in constructors of inherited classes, that can go wrong. Avoid calling methods on classes that aren't fully constructed yet.

Comment: "_Let's suppose that Foo has a noargs constructor which calls someMethod_" <- that's the dangerous part. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html ("Methods called from constructors should generally be declared final. If a constructor calls a non-final method, a subclass may redefine that method with surprising or undesirable results.")

Comment: @ModusTollens the idea is that the class `Foo` is written by someone else, not under the control of the developer. We may disagree with their approach, but it's not something we can influence. My example here is Selenium `HtmlUnitDriver`. It has a method `modifyWebClient` which a developer can override to implement custom behavior. Admittedly the javadoc does not make it clear at all when that method gets called during the lifecycle. But from the source code, I can see that it's called from a private method `createWebClient`, which itself is called from the constructor.

Comment: Ok, so the situation is a little different than the one given in the question. In it, you wrote that "someMethod" is called in the super class controller and it was overridden in your example. The actual super class calling a private method is no problem. You should probably alter your question text to reflect the actual code.

Comment: But that means that the method "someMethod" is not overridden, right? Because it is private in the parent class? If yes, you could just add x and y as parameter. (If this isn't the case, please edit the question with a complete minimal example including the parent class)

Comment: @ModusTollens The way I read the comment above is that the super class constructor calls private method `a()` which in turn calls method `b()`. The OP wishes to override `b()`. The missing detail here: is `b()` also private?

Comment: @AdamBurley Is `HtmlUnitDriver.modifyWebClient()` also private?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I agree, but the question should be edited to reflect the actual problem. Users can't be expected to hunt for important information in comments...

Comment: The assignment to `x` and `y` is always after the call to `super()`. So they will have the default value from any method called by the super constructor. One of the reasons you should not call overrideable methods in a constructor. in my opinion the easiest way is: force an interface and some `someMethod()` method that is called by your framework.If i was this "other developer" i would just create a factory method and do `Foobar.create(x,y) { Foobar f = new Foobar(x,y); f.someMethod(); return f; }`

Comment: @ModusTollens the situation is not different from the one given in the question. In one case, a constructor calls a private method, which itself calls a non-final public method. In the other case, a constructor directly calls the non-final public method. This amounts to the same thing, it doesn't make a difference for the purpose of the question. In the example I gave, `someMethod` is still overridden, and is not private in the parent class. I don't think what we are discussing in the comments is "important information" as you put it. The question already reflects the actual problem.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice in the example I gave in my comment reply to Modus Tollens, `HtmlUnitDriver.modifyWebClient()` is not private. It is analogous to `someMethod` in the question. I have edited the question to say that `someMethod` is not private. If it was, I would not be able to override it, so I thought that was clear from the question.

Comment: @AdamBurley Well, it was pretty obvious for me with the question stating "_Foo has a noargs constructor which calls `someMethod`_" and then overriding "`someMethod`" in your code. To be honest, the question would be better if we could see actual code - it hasn't got to be the original one. Show us the parent class and your implementation attempt. If it stands as it is now (including the quote I have given) my first two comments still apply.

Comment: @ModusTollens I have edited the question to give the parent class source, I am not sure that this adds anything to the question. I am not sure what you mean by "and your implementation attempt" as I have already given the source of my workaround solution based on the inner class and can't think of any other solution which is why I asked the question.

Comment: @AdamBurley With that I meant that it should fit the example parent class, i.e. not override a method called `someMethod` but the actual overridden one.

Comment: @ModusTollens not sure what you mean. In my question `someMethod` **is** the actual overridden one.

Comment: I just saw your edit. I am sorry, I am not trying to be difficult, but that parent class does _not_ describe your actual problem as stated in the comments. It is now, again, a constructor that calls a public, non final method and you override it. That solution is a recipe for disaster and _not_ what you described in comments.

Comment: @ModusTollens as mentioned above, the example I gave in the comments is not materially different from the question. I can only repeat what I said above "In one case, a constructor calls a private method, which itself calls a non-final public method. In the other case, a constructor directly calls the non-final public method. This amounts to the same thing, it doesn't make a difference for the purpose of the question" - what is the difference from your perspective?

Comment: @k5_ the class `Foobar` was only created for the purpose of my workaround solution. I am trying to find if this pattern is standard or whether there is any other design pattern which avoids `Foobar` altogether.

Comment: @AdamBurley I'm sorry, I'm done for today (past bedtime over here). I'd still like to see the actual parent code - so I can understand what it is you want to do and what problems might occur. It's still dangerous to call an overrideable method from a constructor, be it through a private method called by a constructor or not, so the parent class you posted is a no-go in itself. Maybe the Javadoc on the public method would give some insight? Out of curiosity, is the source code of the parent class to be found somewhere online?

Comment: @ModusTollens I am not trying to call an overrideable method from a constructor, that has already been done from the parent class. My question is about the general design pattern, I just gave `modifyWebClient` as an example in the comment. In the case of that example, you can find the source code here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/blob/master/src/main/java/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.java#L229

Comment: It seems you attempt to alter _construction_ of an object of class `Foo` such a way that wasn't allowed by Foo's author. Frankly speaking it looks like a hack, an invasion. The questions are why do you need this, what goal are you trying to achieve?

From my point of view one should clearly distinct between object creation and subsequent object behavior. While the latter is a subject to adjust (that's the whole point of inheritance concept), the former is a sort of private life

Some languages, e.g. C++ clearly moves parent object construction out of child's scope,and that's for the good